# Нейронная сеть на Python. Что это?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Вопрос касается изучения Нейронных сетей на Python. Причем, для человека, который понятия не имеет, что такое и как работают данные сети. Google не дал ни одной полезной ссылки, ни одной вменяемой статьи, где русским языком для не сведущего человека обьяснили, что это такое и с чем его едят. Я, конечно, немного утрирую, и после обобщенного экскурса в биологию можно представить себе, как работают нейронные сети в общих чертах, но тут начинается: "Нейронные имеют  невыпуклую функцию 
вероятности, что приводит к 
проблеме локальных
 максимумов",  "Инициализируем матрицу весов случайными данными", "Создадим сеть из 10 нейронов, 20 слоев и 100500 входов", "Подадим входной сигнал и научим сеть отличать темное пиво от светлого" и т.д. и т.п. Никто и нигде не объясняет, почему для конкретной задачи, требуется именно сколько нейронов, два, а не восемьдесят слоев, какие именно данные и в каком виде  поступают на вход? Сколько килограмм взвешивать на весах? Это тайна или я совсем тупой?Объясните...

Comment: Два раза прочитал вопрос, но так и не понял, причем тут python и в чем заключается вопрос. И как вы вообще собираетесь изучать что-то на каком-то языке, если понятия не имеете, что это такое? [Раз статья для начинающих][1],

[Два статья для начинающих][2]


  [1]: http://grey.colorado.edu/CompCogNeuro/index.php/CCNBook/Main
  [2]: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16419/AI-Neural-Network-for-beginners-Part-1-of-3

Comment: Я когда то разбирался по [этой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/67194/) статье и там есть почему на выходе столько, что на входе и сколько посередине.

Comment: Очень короткая статья: [Нейронная сеть - введение](http://robocraft.ru/blog/algorithm/558.html) Еще книга хорошая есть [Элементарное введение в технологию нейронных сетей с примерами программ](http://www.books.ru/books/elementarnoe-vvedenie-v-tekhnologiyu-neironnykh-setei-s-primerami-programm--perevod-s-polsk-i-d-rudinskogo-858365/) "Автор излагает материал без единой формулы; он ведет диалог с читателем и постепенно подводит его к пониманию механизмов функционирования человеческого мозга и к осознанию перспектив их использования для управления современными техническими и экономическими систем

Comment: Могу дать ссылку на два видео одного блогера на YouTube. Оба видео относятся к одному циклу видео о нейросетях. Если считаете нужным - послушайте. Лично мне всё стало понятно. Вот первое: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxXHYCVrnxk. Вот второе: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c89HzsRI0Sg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Никто и нигде не объясняет, почему для
> конкретной задачи, требуется именно
> сколько нейронов, два, а не
> восемьдесят слоев

Это одна из задач, которую пока решает человек методом подбора исходя из своего опыта в проектировании нейросетей. (Другая серьезная задача - это способ обучения)

По нейросетям могу порекомендовать отличное [введение](http://www.dkriesel.com/en/science/neural_networks).

Что касается Python, для начала, чтобы поиграться, вам хватит PyBrain - это, на данный, момент, как мне кажется, самая простая библиотека.